# regex get word before character that is between other characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the text from a css files, it's all the text that is before the : (overflow, white-space, width, margin-top) and make it blue

```
.MenuContainerScroll {
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}
```

i am using the following regex:

```
html.replace(/(([A-z'-]+)\:)/g, '<span class="blue">$1</span>');
```

what works perfect, until it meets this:

```
.MenuContainerScroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 6px;
height: 1vw;
}
```

now .MenuContainerScroll also turns blue, what i would like it to select every word before the : between the { } does that make sense? I get to select text between with

```
(/(\/\*(.*?)\*\/)/g
```

but i don't get how to combine these two, thanks

Comment: sorry yes it did, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prepend an anchor to assert the start of the string, match optional whitespace chars in group 1 `([^\S\r\n]*)` before the character class, and capture the match from the character class `([A-Za-z'-]+:)` in group 2.

```
^([^\S\r\n]*)([A-Za-z'-]+:)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p3oeRS/1)

In the replacement use

```
$1<span class="blue">$2</span>
```

---

If you want to assert a curly bracket before and after, you might also use lookarounds with an infinite quantifier in the positive lookbehind if that is supported.

```
(?<={[^{}]*)([^\S\r\n]*)([A-Za-z'-]+:)(?=[^{}]*})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KkOoej/1)

Note that asserting the curly brackets does not take any nesting or balanced parenthesis into account and `[A-z]` [matches more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) than `[A-Za-z]`